# How to get the folder path using Intent on Android

Tags: java, android

To get the file path I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT doesn't allow to select folder. 
But how to get the folder/directory path?

API level 19.

Are there ways to do this without third-party libraries?

Answer (score 3):

> To get the file I use

That code has little to do with files. Content != file.

> But how to get the folder/directory?

Build your own UI for this. Or, use [a third-party directory chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created).

> Are there ways to do this without third-party libraries?

There is no platform-defined `Intent` for choosing a filesystem directory. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` will let the user choose a document tree on Android 5.1+, but a document tree is not necessarily a filesystem directory, just as `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` do not necessarily involve files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create constant in your activity class:

```
private static final int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
```

When you need to pick a folder use intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And after user selected folder you will get result in

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    String folderPath = data.getDataString();
        //TODO
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: I use this approach.
ACTION_GET_CONTENT doesn't allow you to select a folder. Only files.

Comment: This opens the file manager "My Files" (samsung note 10) but it shows no content in internal folder.

Answer (score 0):

for picking any folder u can use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("file/*");
  startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

after getting the file show its details as

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
String FileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
int lastPos = FilePath.length() - FileName.length();
String Folder = FilePath.substring(0, lastPos);

textFile.setText("Full Path: \n" + FilePath + "\n");
textFolder.setText("Folder: \n" + Folder + "\n");
textFileName.setText("File Name: \n" + FileName + "\n"); }
```

here is an example how you can do that hope this makes fully clear:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/04/more-for-pick-file-using.html

Comment: Cannot get subfolder. I am testing on Android 11.