# How to select a directory in Android API < 21?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to let the user choose a directory via the Android file picker in Android with API < 21? Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is available since API 21 so can't use it. Do I have to make my own "file picker" or use some library to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh sorry use ACTION_GET_CONTENT it would help

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent, RESULT_CODE);
```

To retrieve Directory

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == Statics.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
        {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
}}
```

the uri will give you the file's directory as URI.

"There is no platform-defined Intent for choosing a filesystem directory. ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE will let the user choose a document tree on Android 5.1+, but a document tree is not necessarily a filesystem directory, just as ACTION_GET_CONTENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT do not necessarily involve files."

[How to get the folder path using Intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101608/how-to-get-the-folder-path-using-intent-on-android)

Comment: ACTION_PICK opens an app chooser instead of the file manager.

Comment: ACTION_GET_CONTENT lets me choose a file not a directory

Comment: You should retrieve directory with On Activity Result Method

Comment: But with ACTION_GET_CONTENT I can't pick an empty directory, like with the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: From what I've read so far, I can't do it with standard Android file picker cause when directory is empty I can't pick anything thus can't retrieve anything in onActivityResult() so I'm gonna use some library. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Piotr as far as I unsderstand, your understanding is true. With your question I learned it too, thank you.